# Left Join same table twice

Tags: postgresql

Lets say we have two tables:

```
Table 1:
    a b      c
    1 Apple  Sheep
    2 Banana Horse
    3 Orange Eagle

Table 2:
    d       e
    Apple   10
    Banana  20
    Organge 10
    Sheep   100
    Horse   300
    Eagle   400
```

As result of a join we want to get table 3:

```
a b      c     d  e
1 Apple  Sheep 10 100
2 Banana Horse 20 300
....
```

With the following sql its possible to achieve:

```
SELECT 1.a, 1.b, 1.c, x2.e, y2.e FROM table1 1
LEFT JOIN table2 x2 ON 1.b = x2.d
LEFT JOIN table2 y2 ON 1.c = y2.d
```

It is working but somehow weird to join the same table twice. Is there a smarter solution?

Comment: This already is a very reasonable solution, and while it may seem weird to you, you basically do need two joins here.

Comment: As long as column table2.d has unique or primary key constraint, this is nothing wrong with this.